# How to Remap the Raspbian "Wheezy" Keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard-layout, raspberry-pi

I am having a strange problem.

I just finished setting up my wonderful Raspberry PI, and it works great... except for the fact that it is not compatible with my [Mac OSX Keyboard](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/) **NOTE:** *I have the wired version - they just don't sell that anymore.*

I can type perfectly well - letters and numbers work fine. But, if I attempt to write `"`, the output is `@`. If I write the `@` symbol, `"` comes out. This is extremely annoying - I was hoping to use the raspberry pi to test LAN networks in Python - the `"` symbol is essential.

**How can I remap my keyboard to fix this?**

Comment: It sounds like a UK/US keyboard layout issue similar to this http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=38081

Comment: I have reposted this question [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/5601/6609)

Comment: Please don't crosspost. If you feel you'd have a better chance on the raspi SE site, flag it for migration instead

Answer (score 2):

You're using a UK keyboard when you think you have a US keyboard - the 2 on a UK keyboard maps to " when it maps to a @ on the US/international one.

In theory, using raspi-config should let you change the keyboard configuration, or by changing the locale. The former seems to be the 'logical' way but I can't quite get that to work. The latter should work by changing it from a gb locale, to a US locale, since the raspi is so very british.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the Raspberry Pi keyboard configuration is set to 'gb' (Great Britain). Keep in mind who is producing this cool little device. :)

Raspbian's X client doesn't provide a way to change this via some GUI application(that I know of). Just edit the keyboard configuration file manually using some text editor. I use vim in this example.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/default/keyboard
```

Find the following line:

```
  XKBLAYOUT="gb"
```

Change it to (assuming you want US keyboard layout):

```
XKBLAYOUT="us"
```

Reboot.